# Cannot read property 'HTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, undefined

I get this strange error with Angular 2.0 RC4

```
Cannot read property 'HTML' of undefined
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My th</title>
  <base href="/">

  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="ihc" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top brand">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse"></div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-content">
             <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}<script src="{{.}}"></script>{{/each}}
   <script src="vendor/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
   <script src="vendor/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  provideRouter(AppRoutes)
  ,HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})

])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here's the exception from DEV Console

```
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'HTML' of undefined
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:29:47)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:59:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:60:3)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js:18:29)
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/compiler.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/compiler.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/main.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'HTML' of undefined(…)


zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'HTML' of undefined
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:29:47)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:59:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:60:3)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js:18:29)
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/compiler.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/compiler.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/main.js
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:29:47)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:59:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js:60:3)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js:18:29)
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_security_schema.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/compiler.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/compiler.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/main.js
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:523:18)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:18
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:36)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

I'm breaking my head to figure out how to troubleshoot this

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is being downvoted? It's a legitimate issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually because Angular2 can't find a script you have declared. And it instead of returning javascript, it is returning html (usually the index page).

What you need to do is open dev tools on the page throwing the error, and look at the network tab. Go through each file and check the response. One of the scripts will most probably be returning html instead of javascript as your paths are incorrect or the file is missing.